# How do you catch an UnknownHostException in android?

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to post then retrieve something in Android, which works great, but when I dont have a internet connection it forces close, is their a way to catch UnknownHostException when making an HttpPost? I know I could make sure its connected to the internet before making the request, but what about if the phone just doesn't have service?

Comment: Checkout this answer about Android's `ConnectivityManager`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009133/180740

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UnknownHostException** is a Subclass of [IOException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html), so you should be able to catch/manage it simply catching IOException or something more specific (NoRoute, ConnectTimeout, etc.)

Also consider adding connection check **before** doing network calls with `ConnectivityManager`

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 3):

you can check for your intenet connection with

```
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected() || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()) {
                    //connected
            } else {
                    //not connected
            }
```

And set the permissions in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```